# Form continues to submit despite custom validation logic

Tags: javascript

I have developed some logic to display relevant errors when the form is submitted, but it continues to allow me to submit the form without displaying the errors. I used a flag to determine whether the form should be submitted, but it seems to be ignored, it's just not working.

```
 if (this.formId == "challengeQuestionAuth") {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        debugOut("Question: " + _this.payload.question, "alert");
        let div = document.createElement('div');

        div.innerHTML = `
            <div id="contentWrapper" style="display: block;">
              <div class="page">
              <div class="page-body">
              <div>
                <div class="page-title">Online Banking Security Challenge</div>
                  <div class="main-section">
                    <div class="page-instructions">
                      This action requires you to answer a security question before it can be completed.
                    </div>
                    <form class="form" method="post" name="security_challenge" id="security_challenge">
                      <input type="hidden" />
                      <div class="validation-summary-valid alert alert-error" data-valmsg-summary="true">
                        <span>
                          Please correct the highlighted field(s) below.
                        </span>
                        <ul>
                          <li style="display: none;"></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      <div class="content-panel">
                        <fieldset>
                          <input name="Text" id="Text" type="hidden" value="What is your best friend's middle name?" />
                          <input name="" id="" type="hidden" value="" />
                          <div class="challenge-question">
                            <label for="challengeResponse">
                              ${_this.payload.question}
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="challenge-answer">
                          <input aria-required="true" name="challengeResponse" class="control" id="challengeResponse" autofocus="autoFocus" type="password" autocomplete="off">
                          <span class="error"><p id="answer_error"></p></span>
                          <input class="checkbox" id="ShowAnswer" type="checkbox">
                          <label class="label" for="ShowAnswer">Show answer</label>
                          <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Answer"></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="action-group-bottom">
                            <a id="cancelButton" class="cancel-button contextual-link" href="">Cancel</a>
                            <input name="Action:SecurityQuestion" id="continueButton" class="primary-action orange-button" type="submit" data-clear-alerts="true" value="Submit" />
                          </div>
                        </fieldset>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                <div aria-required="true" name="challengeQuestion" type="text" id="challengeQuestion">${_this.payload.question}</div><br />
                <label class="control-label" for="challengeResponse">Response:</label>
              </div>
            </div>
              </div>
            </div>`;

        uiContainer.appendChild(div);

        document.getElementById("security_challenge").onsubmit = function() {
          const answer = document.forms["security_challenge"]["challengeResponse"].value;

          const submit = true;

          if (answer == null || answer == "") {
            answerError = "Please provide an answer.";
            document.getElementById("answer_error").innerHTML = answerError;
            submit = false;
          }

          return submit;
        }
```

Here is a minimally reproducible example:

https://codepen.io/ldco2017/pen/dyMMpjb?editors=0010

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: in your if, you are only checking for null or empty, but undefined will go through, change your if to if(! answer) this will check for null, empty and undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to disallow the form to be submitted with what I have below. Adding strict comparison operator to `if` statement and change `const submit` to `let submit` because you are reassigning it.

```
let submit = true;
if (answer === null || answer === "") {
 answerError = "Please provide an answer.";
 document.getElementById("answer_error").innerHTML = answerError;
 submit = false;
}
```